# R data.table grouping - possible to include missing data?

Tags: r, data.table

My title isn't very clear but hopefully an example will help. Say I want to plot the monthly sales data for different items sold at a store - the quantity of items sold and revenue, for each unique item offered for sale by the store.

Example data:

```
sales <- data.table(Item_ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,1,1,4,3,3,2),
                    Sale_Month = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                    Sale_Price = c(1,2,3,4,5,4.5,3.5,1.5,1,4.5,3.5,3,2.5))
```

Example code:

```
monthly_sales <- sales[,
                       .(Monthly_Item_Revenue = sum(Sale_Price),
                         Monthly_Item_Quantity = .N),
                       by = c("Item_ID", "Sale_Month")]
```

The problem is that not all items are sold in all months, so in some months some items are missing. I want '0' values for these items so that they can be plotted.

I've got around it by first making a dummy table with all the items and all the months included, merging with the output of the data.table function, then converting the left over NAs to 0. But this is crude and error prone.

Is there are simpler way to do what I want instead? I'd prefer to stick with data.table because in reality my table is 80 million rows long.

Comment: I know you prefer to stick to `data.table` but a solution using `tidy` could be to use the `fill()` or `complete()` functions. I don't use `data.table` often so I am not sure if it has analogies to these functions.

Comment: yeah maybe something like sales[CJ(Sale_Month, Item_ID, unique=TRUE), on=.NATURAL, .(Sale_Month, Item_ID, Sale_Price=fcoalesce(Sale_Price, 0))]